# How do I log the URL which triggered an error in PHP error logs?

Tags: php

My PHP errors are logged to a file.

The error includes the script that triggered the error. But not the actual URL that calls the script.

This is important, because some scripts rely on data from the URL as an input.

Is it possible to configure how the errors are logged so to include the URL?

If not, since I know the script that triggered the error, is it possible to include some function that logs the URL?

Comment: Sounds like you want [Mapped Diagnostic Context](https://dzone.com/articles/mdc-better-way-of-logging-1). There's a few options available like [this Monolog processor](https://github.com/stevenrombauts/monolog-mdc)